# What do you do if a legitimate answer looks like spam to the forum software?

Tags: support, answers, user-interface, new-users

I typed up an answer to a question about feral cats and when I try to submit it I keep getting a red box saying it looks like spam.

What do I do? What is it keying off of?

I promise you that it is not spam.

Maybe it is too long?

I just don't know.

I've been posting over at Stack Overflow (a computer Q&A site) for a while now and have never encountered this.

Comment: Do you still have a copy of what you tried to post, that got rejected?  If you can put it somewhere public (Google doc, gist, a text file on your personal web space, whatever), that might help people figure out what went wrong.

Comment: No, I trashed it after the modified answer was accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to answer with, but if the answer is basically a link, you might be tripping the filters. Or, perhaps, phrasing or links within have been previously linked to accounts that have been deleted for spam and so are tripping the automated systems.

However, I can't really help, moderators can't override that aspect of the system.

Comment: I was answering the question at http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for/10471#10471  I had one link in the original answer, it was to http://sugarcatsimon.com  I posted a cut down version of my original answer without any links. I'm surprised that I got an up vote on that answer.

Comment: @SimonT - Well, hopefully one of the SE folks will reach out to get some details. Not much I can do, I'm afraid, but the answer you posted certainly looks good by me.

Comment: yes, there was no problem when I posted that answer. Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Ah -- I did have a link in the answer - is there a reputation level needed for including links in answers?

Answer (score 2):

I saw your [posted answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10468/how-can-i-move-houses-with-a-friendly-feral-cat-i-care-for/10471#10471) before seeing this meta post. The answer you posted is fairly long.  I wonder if you tried to post a very long answer and it tripped a filter for "too long" for a new user. I see that was your first attempted post.  If you still have the content you can try updating your post.

Comment: Is there a published length limit for questions and answers as there is for comments? If so, what is it or where can I find out?  I usually do post long questions and answers to try and fully cover the issue. I always go back and edit and chop out a lot and reword, but they are still long. Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: I think it was just because it was your first post and you had not earned any rep yet.

Comment: @SimonT the length limit on posts is 30,000 characters.  I've actually seen a post that legitimately ran up against that limit, but *most* of the time you don't need quite that much.